# How to write @ApiResponse which may return a Class or a List of that class using OpenAPI 3 Swagger in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, swagger-ui, openapi, swagger-3.0

As written in documentation we can use anyOf with @Schema if we want to define multiple responses.

```
    @ApiResponse(responseCode = "201", description = "OK",
        content = @Content(schema = @Schema(anyOf = {Product.class, Activity.class})))
```

My controller returns either a `Product` or a `List<Product>`. I would like to specify this in my OpenAPI 3 documentation.
I would like to know if it's possible.
If Yes, then how?
If No, then is there any workaround?

I don't only want to specify `List.class`. I want to specify `List<Product>`.

P.S.:- Searching on Google didn't get me any results that I can use.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, thats a tough one.

Basically if you really want to return a List of Objects or one Object, then you can create a basic interface like this

```java
public interface Response {
}
```

And then you can create your Object, which implements the response

```java
public class Hello implements Response {
    private String message;

    public Hello(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return this.message;
    }
}
```

Finally we can create the List of our Object. For that we need to create a class, which extends the ArrayList and implements our Interface

```java
public class HelloList extends ArrayList<Hello> implements Response {
}
```

After that we can just set our schema as implementation

```java
@ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "hello world", content = @Content(mediaType = "application/json", schema = @Schema(implementation = Response.class)))
```

---

On the Clientside you need to check the instance of the Response-Object, so that you can parse either the Object or the List

```java
Response response = someCall();
if (response instanceof Hello) {
    System.out.println(processHello((Hello) response);
}
if (response instanceof HelloList) {
    System.out.println(processHelloList((HelloList) response);
}
```

---

This example works, but its very very complex und confusing. A better way to design your api, would be to return just the list. I don't see the benefit to seperate one object or the list of it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for responding.
But I was looking for some kind of annotation-based answer. I can always create a class that consists of a list of the required object and then pass it as schema. But this is a lot of work for just documenting stuff. Isn't there something straightforward?

Comment: Personally, I recommend that you use the [Openapi Generator](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator) to document and generate your Endpoints (but atm it has limited anyOf implementation).

The other way would to just use `Product.class`  and `List.class`, but this is not what you want.

Honestly I dont know your usecase, but i would just go for a single `List<Product>` Endpoint

Comment: Yeah, I would do that too. But the code base is really huge and I am not allowed to change the behavior of any controller.

Comment: Even though this is not what I need, I gave the bounty as it is expiring anyway.

Comment: Without the interface, just using HelloList.class seems ok.